# jabber server returned data

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, xmpp

I am developing a chat application using flex, which can use different service providers users like gmail,yahoomail,ami etc. Almost similar like meebo.com.

I am using jabber server..

My question is what kind of information jabber returns.
I am getting userid,password,status,status message but I am not getting address or phone number of the user or picture of the user..

Please let me know,how can I take these values and what should I pass to jabber server to revcieve full information from jabber for different service provider's users.

waiting for answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XEP-54](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) to retrieve personal information about a user.